# Python : summation over all permutations

Tags: python, list

I am stuck with a seemingly easy problem, could someone please help?

I have two lists `a` and `b`. I can call the elements of the list as `a[i][j]` where `0<i<100` and `0<j<100`.

I want to find all the `a[i][j] - b[k][l]`, where `0<i<100, 0<j<100, 0<k<100` and `0<l<100`. And then do **summation over all permutations** of `i, j, k, l`.

Anyone knows an elegant simple way to this??

Comment: Have you tried `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: You wrote you want to find `all the a[i][j] - b[k][l], where 0<i<100, 0<j<100, 0<k<100 and 0<l<100` -- but some condition seems missing? You want to find all differences which are positive or something?

Comment: If I understand correctly than result is `100*100*(sum(sum(sa) for sa in a) - sum(sum(sb) for sb in b))`. Each element is counted 10000 times, ones from `a` with positive sign, those from `b` with negative.

Comment: Kevin, I have not yet tried that..

Frerich, I want to find all the differences and sum over them. Whether positive or negative.

Comment: Have you tried `for i in range(1,100): for j in range(1,100): for k in range(1,100): for l in range(1,100): total += a[i][j] - b[i][j]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
sum(a[i][j] - b[k][l] for i, j, k, l in itertools.product(range(1, 100), repeat=4))
```

`itertools.product` is equivalent to a nested `for` loop.  It will run over every `(i, j, k, l)` tuple from `(1, 1, 1, 1)` to `(99, 99, 99, 99)`.  **This will skip zero**, which you seem to have asked for.

Comment: Also, one more question.. is it possible to call these values of `a[i][j] - b[k][l]` as say `s(i,j,k,l)` or `s[i][j][k][l]`??

Comment: The former would probably be easier than the latter.  Just define a function which returns suitable values (i.e. `lambda i, j, k, l: a[i][j] - b[k][l]`).  Supporting `s[i][j][k][l]` is also possible, but it requires finagling classes in a most annoying fashion.

Answer (score 2):

This is way faster:

```
(sum(map(sum, a)) - sum(map(sum, b))) * len(a) * len(b)
```

Since you are calculating the sum of the total difference of the arrays. It will work in O(n), but Kevin's answer using itertools is in O(n^2).

I haven't proven it (***edit***: [here's a proof outline](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KKdgjGxQ)), only tested using two random 100x100 arrays, but it's kind of intuitive if you think about it.

The code above will, like Kevin pointed out, assume that your arrays are 100x100 and will include 0. I assumed that you simply wanted to use two 100x100 arrays and got the notation a bit messed up - if you actually want to skip 0 and don't know the size of the array, then you can use the following snippet instead:

```
from itertools import product

C = 100

def _sum(arr, a, b):
    return sum(arr[i][j] for i, j in itertools.product(range(a, b), repeat=2))

answer = (_sum(a, 1, C) - _sum(b, 1, C)) * (C-1)**2
```

Not as pretty, since we are iterating over a submatrix, but still fast. If you want to use [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html), the sliced version can be written a little bit more concisely:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(a, np.int32)
B = np.array(b, np.int32)
answer = (np.sum(A[1:100, 1:100]) - np.sum(B[1:100, 1:100])) * 99**2
```

Comment: OP wants to skip zero and we don't know the lengths of the arrays..  You'll need to add some `[1:100]` slices.

Comment: Sure, I just gave the general algorithm if you have two 100x100 arrays and you don't want to skip 0.

Comment: Also, my solution is O(n^2), not O(n^4).  It runs over 99^4 items, yes, but if we take n=99^2 (the number of elements in one array), that's quadratic, not quartic.

Comment: Sorry you're right about that. Kept thinking of N as 100, not 10000. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, fixed it.

Comment: Nice way :) thank you!Also, one more question.. is it possible to call these values of `a[i][j] - b[k][l]` as say `s(i,j,k,l)` or `s[i][j][k][l]` ???

Comment: Not sure what you mean - are you looking for a nicer syntax for multi-dimensional arrays in Python? You can write it like `a[i, j]` if you are using [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), for example.

Comment: `s(i,j,k,l) = a[i][j] - b[k][l]`. So `s` is a function of not just `i` and `j` but if `i,j,k,l`.. i was wondering if i could call it as `s(i,j,k,l)` or `s[i][j][k][l]`

Comment: I guess you could just define `def s(i, j, k, l): global a, b; return a[i][j] - b[k][l]` , but in my code I'm not using `a[i][j] - b[k][l]` directly so it's not possible to incorporate it it in the code above. What's your motivation? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try generating the Cartesian produce of the array ranges to get the indices.

```
import itertools

cprod = itertools.product(range(1, 100, 1), range(1, 100, 1), range(1, 100, 1), range(1, 100, 1))
result = sum([a[cp[0]][cp[1] - b[cp[2]][cp[3] for cp in cprod])
```